# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects' with keras_self_attention

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I'm making a LSTM network with an attention layer, but when I add the attention layer I get the error: AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

It gives the error in the line were it says: from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention

This is my code:

```
def LSTMAttention():
    inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length, 1))
    x = LSTM(units=128, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
             input_shape=(sequence_length, 1),
             dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
    attention_layer = SeqSelfAttention()(x)
    x1 = LSTM(units=32, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
              input_shape=(sequence_length, 1),
              dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False)(attention_layer)
    dense_layer = Dense(32, activation='softmax')(x1)
    outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(dense_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I hope someone can help me with this error!

Comment: What are your Keras and TensorFlow versions?

Comment: I use Tensorflow 2.5.0 and keras  2.3.0

Comment: That version of Keras does not support TensorFlow 2.5

Comment: Which versions do you recommend for using Tensorflow and keras?

Comment: Because if I install tensorflow==2.4.0 and keras==2.2.0 I get this error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'

Comment: You can try to install `Tensorflow 2.5` and `Keras 2.5.0rc0`, this combination works best. You can also refer this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38012) has many workarounds to the above issue. Thanks!